# how to pass an excel object to a jsp file

Tags: servlets

I am reading a excel file now I want to pass it to the jsp file.

I need to pass the `test` object to the jsp file so that I can display it to the browser.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class Readexcl
{
    private String inputFile;
    public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {

        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void read() throws IOException  {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        Workbook w;
        try {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++)
            {
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell(0, i);
                System.out.print(cell.getContents()+" ");
                cell = sheet.getCell(1, i);
                System.out.println(cell.getContents()+" ");
                //cell = sheet.getCell(2, i);
                //System.out.println(cell.getContents());

            }

        }
        catch (BiffException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Readexcl test = new Readexcl();
        test.setInputFile("c:\\DATA.xls");
        test.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: By passing `test` object you can't display contents on jsp.

Comment: then how can i pass ?

Comment: where do you want to pass the object from? from jsp to jsp? servlet to jsp?

Comment: actually i have one java file which reads my excel now i want to tranfer my data to a jsp file so that i can throw it on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a servlet (but the same is valid if you are in a jsp) you don't need to pass anything...just set the apptopriate content type in response, get the ServletOutputStream, read the xls and write using that stream

If you are in a main it unusual but not impossible...just create a servlet that accept base64 encoded data. In your main read the file, encode the stream in base64band then make an http post call to that servlet, posting the encoded data. In your servlet doPost() method decode the data and write out using ServletOutputStream

Comment: can u please explain i am not able to understand.Actually i have read the excel file using java and i want to tranfer it to the jsp file so that i can through it the browser.

Comment: "using Java" means moreless nothing...I assume your example above is what you trying to do: that is, a main method where you read an excel file.  If that is true, then the servlet scenario is not valid. But first a question: Do you know JEE web components? I mean servlets, jsp? Because if you don't know such things I believe my previous post sounds a little bit cryptic for you